# php extension works with CLI, segmentation fault with apache

Tags: php, apache, segmentation-fault, swig

I built a PHP extension using SWIG.  It is a shared lib that I placed in my php project on my linux box.  The project lives in the directory **/var/www/my_web** and the extension shared lib is placed in **/var/www/my_web/resources/library/**.

In the file **/etc/php5/cli/php.ini**, I added the line:

```
extension=/var/www/my_web/resources/library/my_lib.so
```

In the file **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**, I added the line:

```
extension=/var/www/my_web/resources/library/my_lib.so
```

I have a test php page that does the following...

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
print_r(get_extension_funcs("my_lib"));
```

If I run that test page through the cli PHP, everything is fine.  I get html that I could even save and open in a browser.  Looks good.  However, if I actually browse to the page, I get:

```
[Fri Jan 07 11:37:18 2011] [notice] child pid 3918 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Fri Jan 07 11:37:18 2011] [notice] child pid 3919 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

in the apache log.

Other parts of my_web work just fine, but this test page does not.  The other thing I noticed is that if I only do **print_r(get_loaded_extensions());** without the other line, it works in apache and I do see my_lib listed as a loaded extension.  So, it seems only when I try to access my_lib in apache do problems occur.

I am using php 5.3.2, apache 2.2.14, and swig 2.0.1.

Please, any suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) to find where the segfault is coming from.

Comment: If i do a graceful restart of apache [/usr/sbin/apache2ctl graceful], everything works just fine.  Does this mean Apache was not getting the correct shared lib until restarting?

Answer (score 0):

Did you link your extension with libraries also linked to Apache, but different versions/paths?  Try looking at what apache has loaded with e.g. lsof or pmap and compare to ldd of your extension.